# Memory leak when initialise string

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks

Case 1 : I have written following c program and when I checked for memory leak I got memory leakage at this line `str = (char*)malloc(10);` even when I have written statement to free that memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = (char*)malloc(10);
    str = "string";
    printf("length : %ld\n",strlen(str));
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Case 2:

When I replaced `str="string"` with `strcpy()` there is no any leak why it is so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = (char*)malloc(10);
    strcpy(str,"string");
    printf("length : %ld\n",strlen(str));
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Case 1 exhibits undefined behavior: you don't call `free()` on the same pointer that you got from `malloc()`. Whereas in case 2, you do.

Comment: 1) `str = "string";` It was overwritten with a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: case1. `str = "string"` - wrong because it is no copy string operation; must be `strcpy(str, "string")` as in the case2

Comment: @nikniknik2016 std::string? It is C not C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are not same.

In this case, `strcpy(str, "string")` is correct way to copy the "string" to str. str is allocated then you free it. so no memory is leaking.

In case of `str = "string"`, memory allocated to str will lost and it will cause memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

`str = "string";`

After this `str` points to different memory location(on many platforms it will be read only memory). So it no longer points to memory that you allocated via `malloc`. When you call `free(str)` you are trying to free some memory that you aren't suppose to. This is an undefined behavior. It may do nothing, or it may crash. And the malloced memory is being leaked.

`strcpy(str,"string");`

Here the string is copied to already allocated memory pointed by `str`. You own this memory, you copied data to it and then you free it. So there is no problem here.

So the basic difference between the two cases is that in first case `str` points to a different location than the allocated one.

Answer (score 2):

```
 str = (char*)malloc(10);
 str = "string"; <-- You just lost the pointer to the malloced memory. ie. memory leak.
 free(str); <-- Here you are trying to free the `"string"` itself. Not possible.
```

Comment: yes i tried to free  that memory but i got munmap_chunk() error

Comment: yes i tried to free  that memory but i got munmap_chunk() error and i got reason why it is happening so only those pointers can be free by free function which are return by malloc and its friend function that are calloc,realloc                                                                                                  thank u for your help